# probability matrix from digraph adjacency matrix

Tags: graphs, markov-chains

All I have in hand is a adjacency matrix of a digraph with equal weight on every edge, is there a very simple way to convert this to a state change probability matrix?

Comment: Yes. What have you tried?

Comment: the standard way that i'm doing is to sum each row and then divide the row by the sum, like [[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,1,0]] became [[0,1/2,1/2],[1,0,0],[1/2,1/2,0]]. But i got myself thinking if theres any way to do it faster

Comment: This already runs in linear time, and since (virtually) all entries have to be updated, you can't really do any better.